# How do I edit animation in PowerPoint 2013?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Using PowerPoint 2013 on a Windows computer, I created a long animation within one slide. I want to edit the beginning of the animation. However, when I try to edit the animation it goes to the last animation on PowerPoint's timeline.

What should I do to get to the specific section of the animation to edit it?
[image: PowerPoint Animation Screen Shot]

Answer (score 1):

I know what happened. I created a new screen to animate over the screen. So that's why I could not see the previous animated sections. I simply had to move that new screen over, and in doing so, I was able to see the previous animations. Now I can go back and edit the old animation.